# Calling await fetch steps out of my function and does not complete the rest of the code

Tags: javascript, async-await, react-redux

I have a function to load a JSON file containing information in it that looks like this:

```
async function loadJsonFile() {
    try{
        const jsonResponse = await fetch("/config/jsonfile.json", {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json",
            },
         });

         return await jsonResponse.json()
     } catch(e){
         console.log(e.message);
         return e.message;
     }
}
```

However, when debugging my code `loadJsonFile` gets stepped in to. Then hits the line of code with the `await fetch` and then steps out of the function not completing anything else after it. I was wondering if anyone would be able to help?

```
export const getInit = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const json = await loadJsonFile();
        // more code that needs to be completed below...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

It was brought to my attention that I had a typo in my catch statement. I have since fixed that and am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Add another breakpoint to `return await jsonResponse.json()` and in the catch. When going to next statement in an await you will be out of the function because that is the next statement to be executed the next line in the function will executed when the fetch resolves at a later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about doing it with a different syntax like:

```js
function loadJsonFile() {
    return fetch('/config/jsonfile.json', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
            return error.message;
        });
}
```

Comment: I am not opposed to it - just curious where I would be going wrong with my await function. Also, i believe your code returns a promise and not the actual JSON data.

Comment: `async function` return Promise too cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe because of your catch block, you get `err` as error variable but you have used `console.log(e.message); return e.message;` and since `e` is `undefined` it cause an unhandled error accurs. You can change it like this:

```
...
catch(err){
   console.log(err.message);
   return err.message;
 }
...
```

Comment: Good catch! However, this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: don't you get any error in the console?

Comment: unfortunately I did not. Same issue with it stepping out of the function and not hitting any of the code below it.

Comment: could you check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/saeed_shamloo/6xcg0jm2 
seems it works without any problem. It's exactly your code just with change in `catch` block

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to remove the second `await`.

Comment: It would appear that removing the second await does get me closer. and perhaps out of the scope of the question, but it seems to be returning a promise. How would I go about returning the actual JSON data within the promise?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @scapegoat17 You can never return anything but a promise from an async function. The line after `const json = await loadJsonFile();` should either have json or go into the catch block but you cannot step into it because it will not be the next line executed after the await. Instead of setting the breakpoint at the await why not set it to the next line or both?